# Express Router: Cast to ObjectId error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I get the following error **when calling t**he `users/status` **route**:

```
{
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"status\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Users\"",
"name": "CastError",
"stringValue": "\"status\"",
"kind": "ObjectId",
"value": "status",
"path": "_id"
}
```

I am using `find()` mongoose method to get all documents matching a criteria. Now `find()` does not take an `_id` similar to how `findById` does.

Whats weird is the only way I can fix it is to move my `Express Router` definitions around. **(See Below)**

**This way does not work:**

```
// users
router
 .route('/users')
 .get(getAll)
 .post(createNew);

router
 .route('/users/:id')
 .put(updateExisting)
 .get(getOne)
 .post(upload.single('proposal'), uploadFile); 

router
 .route('/users/status')
 .get(status);
```

**This way works:** (Notice how `users/status` and `users/:id` are swapped

```
// users
router
 .route('/users')
 .get(getAll)
 .post(createNew);

router
 .route('/users/status')
 .get(status);

router
 .route('/users/:id')
 .put(updateExisting)
 .get(getOne)
 .post(upload.single('proposal'), uploadFile);
```

**The controller for** `users/status`:

```
let status = (req,res) => {

  User.find({usersProposals: {$exists: true, $not: {$size: 0}}})
     .exec()
     .then((data) => {sendJsonResponse(res, 200, data)})
     .catch(err => {sendJsonResponse(res, 500, err)})

 };
```

**FYI:** Im running mongoose v4.13.4 and express v4.15.5

**Im not sure what Im doing wrong. Seems like I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere.**

Comment: The `/users/status` fulfiils this `/users/:id` with id=status

Comment: @libik so any route after `/users/:id` will try to fulfil an parameter as `:id`. So order of these routes is important then?

Comment: The order is important in your case and well if order is important, it usually means your design is bad. For standard REST there is `/collections/id/collections/id/collections/id`. You should have endpoint /users and use query string like `exists=true` and call it as `/users?exists=true` or `/users?status=true`

Comment: @libik thank you for help! Appreciate it!!! I'm not sure if the design is bad in this situation (please do correct me if I'm wrong). Im using the `Express.js` which handles all the routing.  if the first parameter we pass to app.VERB() contains query strings **(e.g., /?debug=true)**, that information is disregarded by Express.js. For example, **app.get('/?debug=true', routes.index);** will be treated exactly as **app.get('/', routes.index);**. the only way to access Query Strings is `req.query` within express. This is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The second routing technique is correct.

The problem with the first route ordering is that your `.route('/users/:id')` is matched before the route `.route('/users/status')` because the url path `/users/status` satisfies the route `/users/:id`. 
Actually if you pass anything after the `/user/` path, eg, `/users/anythingHere` would be matched by the `/users/:id` route.

This is the way Express.js works. The routes you define are matched sequentially in the order they are defined. Hence, your second routing setup is correct.

Comment: Ah okay. Didn't know that. This helps. So they need to be done in certain order. Is there any documentation on this? I couldn't find anything on the express site. Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: Quick Question: Why doesn't swapping them around cause the same issue? So if I access the `users/:id` route in the second technique should it give me an error as well?

Comment: Unfortunately Express.js has not clarified this in the documentation I think. Regarding your question - In the second case, if your url path is anything except the `/users/status` then it will be matched by the route `/users/:id`.

Answer (score 1):

This is answer that elaborates the REST API design, the answer of Joytman Singh is correct, therefore I do not elaborate it more.

The problem you have encountered basically tells you that your REST design is not correct. The URL should NOT be available by two controllers and the order should not matter (it matters for some pre-handlers, post-handlers but it should not matter between the controllers of the same importance and similar services).

For example, if two controllers are able to catch the same URL, the first one catches it, sends response and end the chain usually. There is possibility you dont even notice it. What happens, when you delete the first one? Well, you would expect to get 404 on that URL and instead of this, it will start executing different code. You dont want this.

The standard REST API design is basically like this: `/collection/id/collection/id...`, in real world you can have i.e `/users/34/images`

If you want list you stop at collection `/users/34/images`, if you want detail, you stop at id `/users/34`

If you need for example filters like "find only users that exists" you should do it with query string `/users?exist=true`. Then in your controller based on these options (with `if (req.query.exist='true')`), you can do different things, but there should be one controller that handles it.

If you need something very special that is connected to i.e. users, but it does not return users object, it can be better to create completely different URL like `/statuses/users` (where users is kind of "id" for statuses) or something like `/statuses?users=1`

Comment: Thank so much for this. It helps a lot! Would using the `if (req.query.exist='true')` within my controller make the controller code quite "busy" (is that how it's meant to be?). I would assume we would have a few `if` statements because we can perform a number queries on a resource like `users`. Also do you know of any online resource that might talk about Good REST designs? Im just trying to make sure I stay within best practices apologies if Im asking too many questions.

Comment: @Skywalker - no, you have to tell somehow your program, what it does mean, when you are asking for exist=true, therefore you have to "if" it somehow. Even different URL is kind of "if" (it basically means "if" url is like this, then find only users that has exist=true). But it is good to keep things that belongs together really together. The principle is called "loose coupling and high cohesion". It is generally used for almost everything and at different levels (modules, classes, controllers)... I do not know any particular link that I can recommend right now, just look to google.

Comment: @Skywalker - "no" at previous comment was reaction to "controller code". Actually controller should only pass these parameters to service methods (set up i.e. booleans "findExist" to true) and service methods should be responsible to call appropriate methods deeper in the code. Controller itself should only parse input/output and give it to service method in a way the service method understand. Still some kind of "if" is required in both - controller and service method.

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback. You've given me a good basic understanding of REST best practices and what I have been doing wrong. I've found a [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do) which seems to do in detail. Again Thanks!